Physics in a wrapped world
I'm working on a 2D game that takes places in a wrapped, toroidal world. Having implemented dynamic chunk loading and unloading in this setting, and a camera, I'm beginning to dread the  idea of moving my complex physics into this world, since every comparison in time and place poses the risk of close objects being treated as though they were on opposite ends of the map if a world edge happens to be between them.
How should I approach this problem?

one idea I had was to make all object coordinates relative to the window of loaded chunks, since no object can appear outside it. Then, I just update all positions every time there's a load operation. This allows us to treat the loaded area is if it were unwrapped, but makes load operations a lot more costly. Having to remember ever type of position to update, such as cached coordinates, might be tricky to maintain. It's also a bit ugly.
another idea is to make a series of comparison functions that test for the case of a wrapped map - ie, they remap the points to be the shortest distance from each other before comparing them. This has the problem that a lot of built in engine operations need to be rewritten to incorporate these alternate comparisons, which introduces a lot of complexity and potential for bugs. It will also likely be a bit ugly.

Are there any better solutions I'm missing?

Your wrap-on-load approach sounds quite sensible, and I don't think it needs to be as expensive as you think. It's just a vectorized addition per object, applied less than once every frame. With the right data layout, this can be made extremely fast. Would you like to elaborate on what's making it ugly in your situation? Folks here may be able to suggest ways to adjust your storage / handling of positions to make it cleaner and more maintainable.

It's just having to remember everywhere playfield coordinates are used, to shift them, and convert them to world coordinates. Object positions are straightforward, but affected coordinates might include stored variables for targeting, path-finding, anticipated collisions, etc. Those data points are stored and governed by object subsystems rather than the base object, which means using interfaces and propagating a signal. It also means debug position prints either "jump," or appear converted from actual values. This is all doable, but writing virtual functions per subsystem feels less clean.

I think the comparison function is not that complicated either. You need one function that finds all nearby objects for a given object anyway. That functions need to incorporate the wrapped world, which is essentially a modulo operation.
